# ZF2 Runtime Constraints like Flow3

Tags: zend-framework2, typo3-flow

How would Flow3 runtime constraints be done ZF2?

Here's snippet from Flow3's documentation.

> Runtime constraints
>
> Runtime constraints are a very poweful feature of FLOW3’s AOP
>   framework. A full reference of the possibilities can be found in the
>   AOP chapter of this documentation. However, this features was mainly
>   implemented to support sophisticated policy definitions and therefore
>   here is a short introduction by two simple examples on how to use it:
>
> Example: runtime constraints usage in the security policy

```
 -   
     resources:
     methods:
       TYPO3_FooPackage_firstResource: 'method(TYPO3\FooPackage\SomeClass->updateProject(title != "FLOW3"))'
       TYPO3_FooPackage_secondResource: TYPO3_FooPackage_firstResource &amp;&amp; evaluate(current.securityContext.party.name == "Andi")
```

> The above configuration defines a resource that matches on the
>   updateProject method only if it is not called with the title arugment
>   equal to “FLOW3”. The second resource matches if the first one matches
>   and the name property of the currently authenticated party is equal to
>   “Andi”.

http://flow3.typo3.org/documentation/guide/partiii/security.html

Comment: You can also try https://github.com/raykolbe/AOPModule

Comment: @Zyava Looks like the module that I've been looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing directly equivalent. I would look at using `Zend\Acl`'s [Assertions](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.advanced.html) system.

Answer (score 0):

I want to introduce an aspect-oriented programming with Go! AOP library and Zend Framework 2. Here is an example to show the power of AOP [ZF2 with Aspect-Oriented Programming](https://github.com/lisachenko/zf2-aspect) (just clone and install dependencies with composer)